# Calling common function for cellClass Function in UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-grid

I am intending to call same function for all columns. I tried many different way to call function. None did work. I am sure i did something silly. If someone can correct me.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableSorting: true,
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name', 
    //cellClass:  howCanIhaveCommonFunction() 
  },
  { field: 'company',
    //cellClass:  howCanIhaveCommonFunction()

  }
]
```

};

```
 // below function this would be common for all columns
  var howCanIhaveCommonFunction = function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) 
  {
          if (grid.getCellValue(row,col) === 'Velity' || grid.getCellValue(row,col) === 'Beryl Rice' ) {
            return 'blue';
          }
          return 'red';
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4yjVbhmfR47cf7FGfyFk?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is a simple mistake, instead of saying just the function name, you are invoking it without any arguments.

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
enableSorting: true,
columnDefs: [
  { field: 'name', 
    cellClass:  howCanIhaveCommonFunction 
  },
  { field: 'company',
    cellClass:  howCanIhaveCommonFunction

  }
]
```

You just made all the arguments null by having those (), just pass the function name and ui-grid will invoke it with right arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly refer below plunker. My question i was trying to use invoking function have as below which did not work. 

var howCanIhaveCommonFunction1 =  function (){ console.log("NOT WORKED") }

However when i did like below it worked.

function howCanIhaveCommonFunction2 (){ console.log("WORKED") }

http://plnkr.co/edit/4yjVbhmfR47cf7FGfyFk?p=preview